# Adding Borders or Shadows to Borderless Applications in KDE

Tags: linux, kde, user-interface, border

I use Kubuntu 23.10 and have multiple apps, that don't use the standard KDE border and titlebar (like [Trilium](https://github.com/zadam/trilium) or [MS Teams](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-microsoft-teams-linux)).It's hard to tell, where the app ends, when there is no border and the app next to it has the same background color.

[Example of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJiVj.png)

Is there a way to add a small border or shadow to applications in KDE that don't use the standard border and titlebar?

Thanks in advance